# Javascript call fails with Uncaught ReferenceError BotChat is not defined in a Web based Javascript Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Context -

I am building a Javascript-based custom component for one of our BI Application.
It is a simple web-based component that lets users to chat with Microsoft bot using DirectLine channel.

With some struggle, I was able to load the botchat library (Javascript file) in the custom component that I am building, but the call to library always throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: BotChat is not defined"

Here is the code I am using to call botchat library with DirectLine channel-

```
                    BotChat.App({
                    directLine: { secret: 'wtt1zOP02nU.cwA.1ww-DUMMY-SECRET' },
                    user: { id: 'TestBot' },
                    bot: { id: 'TestBot' }
                  }, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));
```

There is no issue if I run the code on HTML web page, it perfectly works. While calling in the javascript component, it throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: BotChat is not defined".

I can see that the library is loaded properly - see the Network resources screenshot from chrome -

[image]

Here is the CDN -
https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js

The code in botchat.js is defined as below -

```
    ! function(t, e) 
    {
        "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = e() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], e) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.BotChat = e() : t.BotChat = e()
    }(this, function() {
        return function(t) {
            function e(r) {
                if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
                var o = n[r] = {
                    i: r,
                    l: !1,
                    exports: {}
                };
                return t[r].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, e), o.l = !0, o.exports
            }
...........
........... 
});
```

I tried multiple things already -
Instead of referencing external library, I have copied whole botchat.js code and pasted in the same component function where I call BotChat.App

Also tried using "this.BotChat.App({..});" it still fails.

However, sample test function calls are all OK with same approach for external javascript file/function in the same component js file.

Tried instantiating BotChat, but it fails with error - BotChat is not a constructor. It is basically Object type.

Could you help me with other ways of calling BotChat ?
May be in Jquery? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have a very similar issue, thanks!